# how to convert dynamic php file to pdf?

Tags: php, html, pdf, pdf-generation, dompdf

I try to convert dynamic php database file to pdf.
I try with DOMPDF, but I have a problem with defining the string. I'll explain:

Here is a 'hello world' script for dompdf:

```
require_once(&quot;dompdf_config.inc.php&quot;);
$html =
    '<html><body>'.
    '<p>Hello World!</p>'.
    '</body></html>';
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("hello_world.pdf");
```

The thing is that instead of a simple

```
'<html><body>'.
'<p>Hello World!</p>'.
'</body></html>'
```

I have a long php file full of functions and sql queries. because of it I have inside it many ",',; e.t.c signs. I also have a javascript dynamic chart (jqplot) in this page.

So instead of pdf file I get errors errors errors...

Does anyone has a solution for this?

I will really appreciate any answer, and will be really really thankful for a solution...

Comment: Just to confirm your question, are you attempting to create a PDF of the code itself for some reason, or the **output** of the code?

Comment: Paker's answer should work...

Answer (score 4):

First you'll need to generate HTML from your PHP, then pass it to DOMPDF:

```
<?php
    require_once("dompdf_config.inc.php");
    ob_start();
    require_once("path/to/input/file.php");
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html(ob_get_clean());
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream("file.pdf");
?>
```

You can also do a regular HTTP request:

```
<?php
    require_once("dompdf_config.inc.php");
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html_file('http://example.com/file.php');        
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream("file.pdf");
?>
```

---

If you need JavaScript support, try [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/), it's based on Webkit and does it's work perfectly.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it ( the regular http request) but I get an error that sais : Fatal error: Call to a member function load_html_file() on a non-object

Comment: In @Paker's second example, add $dompdf = new DOMPDF(); between the first and second lines of code.

Comment: Thanks @jcmeloni, answer was fixed.

Comment: I have the same problem. I did this thing but I get  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'DOMPDF_Exception' with message 'Requested HTML document contains no data.' in /var/www/magmito/dompdf/include/frame_tree.cls.php:114. Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ob_start` and `ob_get_contents` to run PHP code and capture the output as a string.

For the JavaScript chart, though, you're out of luck. DOMPDF is pretty smart, but it's not that smart. You'll need to either use a non-JavaScript chart solution, do without the charts, or use a web browser to generate the PDF.

Comment: First of all, Thank you for your help!<br/>
I'v tried what you suggested, hope I understood it well... 
I did it like this:

     '<?php
require_once("dompdf_config.inc.php");<br/>
ob_start(); <br/>
?><br/>
my html+php blabla bla... <br/>
<?php <br/>
$html = ob_get_contents();<br/>
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();<br/>
$dompdf->load_html($html);<br/>
$dompdf->render(); <br/>
$dompdf->stream("hello_world.pdf"); <br/>
?>'<br/>
but now it sais: <br/>
"Unable to stream pdf: headers already sent"<br/>
:-(

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you need to generate HTML to build a PDF in the first place but as others have suggested, build out your PHP script and then use something like [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org) or [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org).

They both build PDFs just fine and can take HTML input.

Answer (score 0):

Try This ...

```
<?php
    ob_start();

    require_once("dompdf_config.inc.php");

    $file = file_get_contents('http://example.com/file.php');

    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($file);
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream("filename.pdf");
?>
```